# MFC - encountering deadly diamond of death

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, diamond-problem

A newbie here in windows programming.

I want to make a dialogbox that uses both `CPropertyPage` and `CDHtmlDialog`?

```
class CPropertyPage : public CDialog  
class CDHtmlDialog  : public CDialog
```

Since I can't change the inheritance for each of the above case to "virtual public", is it still possible to make a dialog that has some fields from `CPropertyPage` and some forms from `CDHtmlDialog`?

Comment: If you are a newbie to Window's programming, I would recommend you learn Window's programming with .NET and C#, not MFC and C++.

Comment: true, but right now have to work with lot of legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the HTML dialog as child dialog of property page. The only problem is that child dialog closes if user pressed cancel. You have to override  `CDHtmlDialog::OnCancel`. Example:

```
class CMyDHtmlDialog : public CDHtmlDialog
{
    void OnCancel()
    {
        //GetParent()->GetParent()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL);
    }
};

class CMyPropertyPage : public CPropertyPage
{
    CMyDHtmlDialog child;
    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        BOOL res = CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();
        child.Create(IDD_HTML, this);
        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);
        child.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you I am hoping this is the answer. Is child dialog embedded inside the CMyPropertyPage?

Comment: Yes, this should be simple. Also the dialog resource for property page (`IDD_PAGE1`) can be blank. Put the controls, if any, in HTML dialog.

Comment: Thank you! I used your concept in a slightly different way and it fixed my problem. much thanks!